# A little clarification on the volatile keyword

Tags: java, volatile

Consider the snippet from Java Concurrency in Practice-

```
// Unsafe publication
public Holder holder;

public void initialize(){
    holder = new holder(42);
}
```

---

```
public class Holder{
    private int n;

    public Holder(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void assertSanity(){
        if (n != n)
            throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
    }
}
```

One of the solutions suggested by the author of the book is -

```
public static Holder holder = new Holder(42);
```

And if the only requirement was to prevent the `AssertionError`, then this would also work fine-

```
private final int n;
```

My question is a follow-up to the comment on this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107683/improper-publication-of-java-object-reference) by John Vint-

> Actually, declaring the member field volatile still doesnt guarantee
>   publication prior to holder being visible. You can look at
>   ConcurrentHashMap's private method readUnderLock in which that takes
>   this nuance into account. Though declaring holder as volatile does.

To put it in simple words, he is suggesting hereby 2 things-

```
public volatile Holder holder;

public void initialize(){
    holder = new holder(42);
}
```

Is the above solution going to work perfectly? If a **reference** to an object is declared as volatile, does it ensures safe object publication? Arrays are objects too. Declaring an array reference doesn't makes its elements thread safe.

And Why this will not work as suggested by author-

```
public class Holder {
private volatile int n;
```

> declaring the member field volatile still doesnt guarantee
>   publication prior to holder being visible

Even though as the member field has been declared as volatile, its gauranteed that the condition `n != n` will be always **false**, and hence no `AssertionError`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `volatile` would help as you suggest, it would not help in many other situations you might happen to try to use. i.e. it's very easy to use `volatile` incorrectly so it would be difficult to encourage unless you can be sure you know which operations will be used.

> If a reference to an object is declared as volatile, does it ensures safe object publication?

This is very dependant on the order and type of operations.  In this case, the write

```
this.n = n;
// and then
holder = ...
```

The write to `holder` ensure the write to `this.n` must be visible assuming you also do

```
Holder h = holder; // read barrier
// n must be set.
int n = this.n;
```

> declaring the member field volatile still doesnt guarantee publication prior to holder being visible

I don't agree in this case. Once you have obtained the `holder` in another thread, there is no chance that reading `n` will fail to see the value initialised as you are reading a volatile variable.  This is because the `holder` is set only after `n` is initialised.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't the author wrong for this specific case.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari I agree, in general `volatile` doesn't provide the guarantees you need, but in this specific case it will happen to work.

Comment: Thanks again, but didn't get your point  for the second code snippet `Holder h = holder;` // read barrier. Please elaborate.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari when you read anything which has a read barrier e.g. reading a volatile, you can be sure to only read data which had been set by that time or after.

Comment: "This is because the holder is set only after n is initialised." are you sure there is such guarantee in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class main {
public volatile static Holder holder;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Unsafe publication
    initialize();
    holder.assertSanity(99);
}
public static void initialize(){
    holder = new Holder(42);
}
}
```

Holder.java

```
 public class Holder {

 private volatile Integer n;
    public Holder(Integer n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void assertSanity(Integer n){
        if (!((Object)this.n).equals((Object)n))
            throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
    }

    public Integer getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public void setN(Integer n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

 }
```