# Differences in safe publishing between volatile,final and synchronized

Tags: java, concurrency

Given a class A with variable x. Variable x is set in class constructor:

```
A() {
x = 77;
}
```

We want to publish x to some other thread. Consider the following 3 cases of variable x thread-safe (?) publication:

1) x is **final**

2) x is **volatile**

3) x is set in **synchronized block**

```
synchronized(someLock) {
A a  = new A();
a.x = 77;
}
```

Thread2 simply prints x:

```
 System.out.println(a.x);
```

The question is: is it possible to observe '0' printed by Thread2? Or it is guaranteed by JMM that '77' will be printed or NPE will be thrown in all 3 cases?

Comment: You can't really publish 'int' - you publish 'A.  And no, only final actually guarantees the safe part (volatile is rather awkward but it doesn't)

Comment: Case 2 is quite academic, see [Doug Lea comment here](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-November/011951.html)

Comment: @KelvinNg, even following the infamous roach-motel the store to the unsafe location of `a` can be moved prior to the volatile store of  `x`... but yeah I recall the heated discussion last summer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer comes from the [best page on the internet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html), in particular chapter 17 that deals with memory visibility and concurrency.

I am also assuming that you do not have reference leaks (I.e. you do not have a reference to the object before the object constructor is finished).

- Final field. I'll just quote the above page on this, chapter 17.5:

  > An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.
- Volatile. Again, I will just quote the JLS:

> A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

Hence, assuming your `Thread` got access to the object after it finished the constructor, it will see the correct value. Note, this means you will likely need to make a volatile as well.

- x is in a synchronized block. This is a tricky one. It may or may not
  be visible. In fact, synchronization only slightly increases the
  difficulty of explaining this, so I will drop it and explain whether
  a simple local variable will be seen here or not. And then add a
  clause about synchronized.

By definition, it is guaranteed to be visible if there is a `Happens-before` relationship between the read and the write. Otherwise it *may* happen that you see an uninitialized value. What constitutes a `Happens-before` relationship? Again, the JLS chapter 17 specifies this, in particular:

- Operation order in a single thread.
- Synchronization, locks and volatility.
- Object and Thread creation.
- Everything is transitive.
- More stuff, read the JLS

Hence there can be two situations:

```
A a = new A();
Thread t = new MyThread(a);
t.start();
```

Where `MyThread` saves the instance of A and uses that. In this case, the thread is created after `a`, and `start()` is called after it is created. Hence visibility is guaranteed, even if `x` is non-volatile. However, visibility of further changes to `x` is not guaranteed.

Situation 2:

This is a little more difficult to code up, but:
Main creates two Threads and immediately starts them, and has a single non-volatile field of type A.
ThreadA creates A and writes it to the shared field.
ThreadB loops through a while until the field is populated and then prints out x.

In this case, even though there is a HB between the write to x and the write to the shared field, there is no HB between read and write of the shared field. Hence there is no guarantee of the visibility of write to x.

As promised - if you put a synchronized block around the write to x in either of these 2 cases, it will not affect the outcome, since there is nothing else locking on the monitor. Locking and unlocking the same monitor creates a synchronization action, and hence create a HB relationship.

Comment: declaring `x` volatile doesn't ensuring seeing the correct value with unsafe publishing of A, as the compiler is free to reorder publishing of `A` and setting the value of `x`. Sync doesn't ensure anything either.

Comment: @bestsss On the sync - given the OP puts the entire object creation and assignment into the synchronized block as he did, and the read is also on this monitor - it does, but without an explicit sync in the read - no guarantees whatsoever. I wasn't sure about case two, I thought a thread cannot give write an object reference before the constructor completely finished. I may be mistaken though.

Comment: Ordous, thats what I was thinking about: there is a HB between volatile write and volatile read, but we dont know when the reader thread will see the reference to the object. It may see a reference to the uninitialized object.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if we make the 'a' field volatile. I.e. volatile A a = new A(); Does this guarantees safe publishing of a.x variable? Or compiler may still reorder the lines and write to volatile field the unitialized object?

Comment: @Dymytry, sure it will be safe. Basically never do unsafe publications. As for reorder, nether the compiler nor the CPU are allowed to move **volatile** writes past any writes/synchronized blocks. However normal writes can be ordered to be prior volatile writes. (by safe I mean all 3 methods are safe)