# Why constructor body guarded by lock in SemaphoreOnLock implementations[JCIP 14.12]

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility

In Java Concurrency In Practice book auhor provides following implementation `Semaphore` on top of the `ReentrantLock`:

```
@ThreadSafe
public class SemaphoreOnLock {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    // CONDITION PREDICATE: permitsAvailable (permits > 0)
    private final Condition permitsAvailable = lock.newCondition();
    @GuardedBy("lock") private int permits;

    SemaphoreOnLock(int initialPermits) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            permits = initialPermits;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: permitsAvailable
    public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (permits <= 0)
                permitsAvailable.await();
            --permits;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            ++permits;
            permitsAvailable.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you explain why do we use lock inside the constructor?

Is it related with visibility?

### P.S.

At same book you can find also [this class](http://jcip.net/listings/SafePoint.java):

```
@ThreadSafe
public class SafePoint { 
    @GuardedBy("this") private int x, y;
    private SafePoint(int[] a) { this(a[0], a[1]); }
    public SafePoint(SafePoint p) { this(p.get()); }
    public SafePoint(int x, int y) { 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public synchronized int[] get() { return new int[] { x, y };
    }
    public synchronized void set(int x, int y) { this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

author says that this class thread-safe.

Comment: this has an answer here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611366/constructor-synchronization-in-java

Comment: @Ousmane Unfortunately - not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Concurrency in Practice - Sample 14.12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528572/java-concurrency-in-practice-sample-14-12)

Answer (score -1):

the changes to int data type is not atomic which is why its guarded with locks

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528572/java-concurrency-in-practice-sample-14-12

Comment: where did you see about atomicity in linke topic?

Comment: Its there, please check

Comment: There is nothing about this

Comment: "Non final fields are first initialized to default value and then the actual assignment will happen" either we should make it volatile or guard by lock

Comment: 1. in your answer you wrote another, 2 In updated my topic I showed where author don't use synchronization in constructor